# Table size not fit

Tags: tables, size

I have problem with the table. My table is very small so it is impossible to read the content.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hlin
& \textbf{Polish}                        & \textbf{Russian}                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ \hline
\textbf{locations}     & USA, Gelsenkirchen                                         & Tурция, Вюртемберг, Йемен                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
 \textbf{names}         & Aneta, Emila Harry, Kaczmarczyk, Antygona, Jason           & Игнатьев, Глеб, Фрейд, Абрамович, Хачатурян                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \hline
\textbf{foreign words} & prêt-à-porter, Bundestag, Done Strangers, vis-à-vis        & Menschengattung, isolated, dort, coding                                                                                                                                                                          \\ \hline
\textbf{numbers}       & 146A, 3x16, 294,8, 1004-A, 100-metrowy, 80-kilogramowy, II & 1615,  76-й, XXI                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
\textbf{emails}        & slawek.sa@gazeta.pl, izaa83@interia.pl                     & birzha\_red@birzhaplus.nnov.ru                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
\textbf{abbreviation}  & KGW, RM,PRL, PCBC                                          & СНГ, PISA МарГУ, 'Тасс                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
\textbf{smilies}       & :),   ;*,  : -(                                            & :)  ; -(                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ \hline
\textbf{punctuation}   & .....!    !???                                             & !!!..                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
\textbf{others}        & O, 'Cz, B, S, O\_o, ;d words without diacritica: ze - że   & rare and old words: вокодер,  уповать, чебурахнуть, отзынить, оофориткалымить; slang: уважуха, дворничиха; name calling: урод, хуй; schimpfwörter,rare words, ти-ли-ти-ли-тили-бом, у-у-у-у-у,п-щ-щ-щ-щ, ай-яй-я \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: never use `\resizebox` on tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "smallness" I think is related to the `resizebox`. I tried another way.

Unfortunately I don't have a cyrillic font. I can only suggest an example which you have to adapt to your setup:

- used `booktabs` for rules
- used `tabularx` for autocalculated wide columns
- used `ragged2e` for the ragged settings suggested by Mico (basically it will yield a better composition)
- removed all the vertical separators (look ugly)
- removed the resizebox
- used the `tabularx` environment with two `Y` columns, defined to be raggedright
- removed the spacing before the first and after the last columns with `@{}`
- also with `>{\bfseries}` before the first column I made sure that it is already set in bold (thanks to Zarko)
- expanded the row separation with `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

nevertheless I feel there still something to be done to pretty your code

So here's the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}lYY@{}}
\toprule
  & \textbf{Polish}            &\textbf{Russian}\\ \midrule
locations     & USA, Gelsenkirchen& Tурция, Вюртемберг, Йемен\\ 
 names         & Aneta, Emila Harry, Kaczmarczyk, Antygona, Jason           & Игнатьев, Глеб, Фрейд, Абрамович, Хачатурян\\ 
foreign words & prêt-à-porter, Bundestag, Done Strangers, vis-à-vis        & Menschengattung, isolated, dort, coding                                                                                                                                                                          \\ 
numbers      & 146A, 3x16, 294,8, 1004-A, 100-metrowy, 80-kilogramowy, II & 1615,  76-й, XXI                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ 
emails        & slawek.sa@gazeta.pl, izaa83@interia.pl                     & birzha\_red@birzhaplus.nnov.ru                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ 
abbreviation  & KGW, RM,PRL, PCBC                                          & СНГ, PISA МарГУ, 'Тасс                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ 
smilies       & :),   ;*,  : -(                                            & :)  ; -(                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ 
punctuation   & .....!    !???                                             & !!!..                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ 
others        & O, 'Cz, B, S, O\_o, ;d words without diacritica: ze - że   & rare and old words: вокодер,  уповать, чебурахнуть, отзынить, оофориткалымить; slang: уважуха, дворничиха; name calling: урод, хуй; schimpfwörter,rare words, ти-ли-ти-ли-тили-бом, у-у-у-у-у,п-щ-щ-щ-щ, ай-яй-я \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If the table is really big you could try with `sidewaystable`, or perhaps `longtable`.

Comment: you can define table columns as `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}lXX@{}` and then remove all `\textbf{...}` in the first  column :-)

Comment: @Zarko of course, I did not even notice that, I was concerned with the cyrillc

Comment: +1. I would also load the `ragged2e` package, issue the directive `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}` in the preamble, and use two `Y` columns instead of two `X` columns. That'll serve to avoid big interword gaps while still permitting hyphenation. On the other hand, the `\centering` instruction may be omitted since the width of the `tabularx` environment is set to `\textwidth`.

Comment: @Mico yes, you're right indeed

Answer (score 1):

Some improvements, using the `description` environment – and a font with cyrillic. To be compiled with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[russian,polish]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{fourier} 
 \setmainfont{erewhon}
\usepackage{array, tabularx,multirow, makecell, enumitem}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\makegapedcells\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| >{\bfseries}l|>{\RaggedRight}X|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
& \textbf{Polish} & \textbf{Russian} \\ \hline
locations & USA, Gelsenkirchen & Tурция, Вюртемберг, Йемен \\ \hline
names & Aneta, Emila Harry, Kaczmarczyk, Antygona, Jason & Игнатьев, Глеб, Фрейд, Абрамович, Хачатурян \\ \hline
foreign words & prêt-à-porter, Bundestag, Done Strangers, vis-à-vis & Menschengattung, isolated, dort, coding \\ \hline
numbers & 146A, 3x16, 294,8, 1004-A, 100-metrowy, 80-kilogramowy, II & 1615, 76-й, XXI \\ \hline
emails & slawek.sa@gazeta.pl, izaa83@interia.pl & birzha\_red@birzhaplus.nnov.ru \\ \hline
abbreviation & KGW, RM,PRL, PCBC & СНГ, PISA МарГУ, 'Тасс \\ \hline
smilies & :), ;*, : -( & :) ; -( \\ \hline
punctuation  & .....! !??? & !!!.. \\ \hline
others & O, 'Cz, B, S, O\_o, ;\newline d words without diacritica: ze - że &\begin{description}[font=\normalfont, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=1em, before= \vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+0.8ex}, after =\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
\item[rare and old words:] вокодер, уповать, чебурахнуть, отзынить, оофориткалымить; 
\item[slang:] уважуха, дворничиха; 
\item[name calling:] урод, хуй; 
\item[schimpfwörter, rare words:] ти-ли-ти-ли-тили-бом, у-у-у-у-у,п-щ-щ-щ-щ, ай-яй-я
\end{description}\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}%
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]